# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact 'annotation-experimental.aar

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and I just created my first application using Kotlin in Android Studio. However, I am getting this error message below. I couldn't start because my app won't build. I already tried `Invalidate Caches/Restart`but nothing happens.

JDK version: 11.0.16.1,
Android Studio version: 3.4.1

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Failed to 
transform artifact 'annotation-experimental.aar (androidx.annotation:annotation- 
experimental:1.3.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath':         
Failed to transform artifact 'annotation-experimental.aar    
(androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0)' to match attributes 
{artifactType=jar}
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Failed     
to transform artifact 'annotation-experimental.aar (androidx.annotation:annotation- 
experimental:1.3.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Failed to     
transform artifact 'annotation-experimental.aar (androidx.annotation:annotation- 
experimental:1.3.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': 
Failed to transform artifact 'annotation-experimental.aar 
(androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0)' to match attributes 
{artifactType=jar}
Affected Modules: app
```

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
   implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wanna share how I resolved this error. I lowered the version of core-ktx from `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0`to `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version
```

have you mentioned the version for  `$kotlin_version` ?